# How do I connect register.com domain to iPower Hosting

Tags: dns, hosting

Sorry if this question is very elementary. I've registered on iPOWER my new domain, however I don't know how to connect my hosting to my domain on register.com.

If anyone uses the two sites detailed instruction would be great. Otherwise maybe there are some steps that have to be taken between any two hosting and domain services that I am missing out on.

Answer (score 0):

In register.com account management page:

Click your domain

In the domain management page, go to last section ADVANCED TECHNICAL SETTINGS

You can customise your CNAME records there. e.g. pointing *.yoursite.com to example.iPower.com

according to [this page](http://help.register.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/487/related/1), it may take 12-24 hours to update.

Hope that helps.